# Common Lisp: unquoting symbol in backquote

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

The following piece of code gives me the expected result:

```
(let ((name 'test)
      (args '("arg1" "arg2")))
     `(defun ,name ,@args))

;; (DEFUN TEST "arg1" "arg2")
```

Why if `args` is a list of symbols does a `QUOTE` appear?

```
(let ((name 'test)
      (args '('arg1 'arg2)))
     `(defun ,name ,@args))

;; (DEFUN TEST (QUOTE ARG1) 'ARG2)
```

Comment: `('arg1 'arg2)` isn't a list of symbols, it's  a list of lists. The first list is `(quote arg1)` and the second is `(quote arg2)`.

Comment: I think the standard printer does newbies a big disservice by printing the data `(quote x)` as `'x`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reader expands `'symbol` to `(quote symbol)`. So in your case

```
'('arg1 'arg2)
```

is equivalent to

```
(quote ((quote arg1) (quote arg2)))
```

which evaluates to this list:

```
((quote arg1) (quote arg2))
```

Evaluating your form starting with the backquote results in splicing the list elements (`(quote arg1)` and `(quote arg2)`) at the same position in the resulting list `(defun ...)` as the strings before.

I don't know why your implementation prints the first spliced element expanded but not the second. However, as mentioned above, both forms are equivalent, when read.

Comment: The pretty-printer will try to print a list starting with `defun` in the most readable way. The canonical form is (`defun` <name> <list of parameters> <body>) so it will print the `(quote arg1)` for the two arguments `quote` and `arg1` and in the body, it'll; use the shorter, possibly more human-friendly `'arg2`.